# How to delete the last element from ruby association input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

How to delete the last element from ruby association input

this is my input form field, which select all sizes and lists

`= simple_nested_form_for [:admin, @product], wrapper: :horizontal_small_form do |f|
  = f.association :standard_sizes, as: :check_boxes`

This is what iam getting when iam inspecting it.
How to remove last option (custom size) from this.

`<label class="check_boxes optional control-label">Standard sizes</label><span class="checkbox"><label for="product_standard_size_ids_1">
<input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="1" name="product[standard_size_ids][]" id="product_standard_size_ids_1">S</label></span><span class="checkbox"><label for="product_standard_size_ids_2">
<input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="2" name="product[standard_size_ids][]" id="product_standard_size_ids_2">M</label></span><span class="checkbox"><label for="product_standard_size_ids_3">
<input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="3" name="product[standard_size_ids][]" id="product_standard_size_ids_3">L</label></span><span class="checkbox"><label for="product_standard_size_ids_4">
<input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="4" name="product[standard_size_ids][]" id="product_standard_size_ids_4">XL</label></span><span class="checkbox"><label for="product_standard_size_ids_5">
<input class="check_boxes optional" type="checkbox" value="10" name="product[standard_size_ids][]" id="product_standard_size_ids_10">Custom Size</label></span><input type="hidden" name="product[standard_size_ids][]" value=""></div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the collection you wish to show with:

```
#rails 4
f.association :standard_sizes, collection: StandardSize.where.not(id: 10)

#rails 3
f.association :standard_sizes, collection: StandardSize.where('standard_sizes.id != 10')
```

But you should probably wonder why you need the field Custom Size in your database...

Comment: Oh, this is Rails4+ solution by the way... I see you tagged this 3.2

Comment: yep, but you should still reconsider having this hard coded value in your database... this could mean probably in the future!